# how to manage multiple ssh key in Ubuntu?

Tags: ssh, openssh

1. Can any body please tell me how to manage multiple ssh keys in
   Ubuntu.
2. how to disable password authentication
3. how to turn off server signature.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow  https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html.en  on how to setup ssh. #2 and #3 is not an issue if you follow the normal install.

Important part in the guide about the SSH keys:

> **SSH Keys**
>
> SSH keys allow authentication between two hosts without the
>   need of a password. SSH key authentication uses two keys, a private
>   key and a public key.
>
> To generate the keys, from a terminal prompt enter (client side):
>
> ```
> ssh-keygen -t rsa
> ```
>
> This will generate the keys using the RSA Algorithm.
>   During the process you will be prompted for a password. Simply hit
>   Enter when prompted to create the key.
>
> By default the public key is saved in the file `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`,
>   while `~/.ssh/id_rsa`  is the private key. Now copy the `id_rsa.pub` file
>   to the remote host and append it to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` by
>   entering:
>
> ```
> ssh-copy-id username@remotehost
> ```
>
> Finally, double check the permissions
>   on the authorized_keys file, only the authenticated user should have
>   read and write permissions. If the permissions are not correct change
>   them by:
>
> ```
> chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
> ```
>
> You should now be able to SSH to the
>   host without being prompted for a password.

Management is done through the ssh-copy command and the `.ssh/autorized_keys` in the guide so that will tackle the title.

That should have you setup a server with ssh keys. ALWAYS have a 2nd account open on that system and make sure you can connect over ssh before exiting the system